# Combo box control in application designer for maximo 7.6?

Tags: maximo

My client's requirement is to have a combo box on one of my custom application in maximo 76. How do I bind a Combo Box in Maximo Application Designer?

Comment: What have you tried already and not been successful with. Can you provide screenshots of the properties of the combo box (all tabs) and your application designer screenshot of layout.

Comment: Just like other text filed control, I tried combobox with custom attribute named (city) to show a list of city names. Question is, from where this control will get cities data.   I have done this task with simple text field and attached an AL domain. But my requirements is to have combo box instead of domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combobox control (dropdown) is a control in Maximo Application designer, mostly users prefer to use domain instead of Combobox, but in Maximo we can see combo in number of different location like in PR application SHIPVIA, or WORKTYPE in Workorder Tracking application.

Drop a control just like text field, 
set properties; there are two most important properties
i. Attribute 
ii. Select Attribute (from where the data comes from, like from ALN domain or from Object)

References : http://maximodeploy.blogspot.com/2016/09/add-combo-box-control-in-pr-using-aln.html

Answer (score 0):

Combo box is like any other attribute you include in Application Designer. You must select the attribute that you want to pull to populate the drop down list.

[Combo box control](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZRHJ/com.ibm.mbs.doc/designer/r_props_combobox.html)

[Changing the value that displays for a Combo Box](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21447290)

Comment: Any example , i already have googled these links, but no luck